# Get max and min values of a facet in Algolia

Tags: javascript, algolia

I'm trying to use the algolia javascript api to create a pretty simple page with some basic filters.

I'm also trying to implement a range slider similar to this one here made by algolia - https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/

I need the min and max values because 'facets_stats' returns the min and max for the current query (but I need the absolute minimum and absolute maximum so I can keep them constant at the edges of the slider)

After digging through the code for that instantsearch widget, I see they are using the algoliasearch helper to get the values (I think) but after playing around with the helper for a bit, I wasn't able to get the values I needed.

I've almost completed my project so it would be a huge waste of time to rewrite it using those components but I can't seem to figure out how to get the min and max values for a facet.

Is there any simple way to get the maximum/minimum value for a numeric facet using a single api call?

Comment: Can you produce an example of your code?

Comment: code can't really be simplified to be pasted here, but the usage is as basic as it gets on https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-js 

example of their slider: https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/examples/tourism/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is performing an initial empty (blank) query to retrieve the `facets_stats` and therefore the underlying `min/max` values for all the records.

```
index.search('' /* match all */, {facets: 'myfacet', hitsPerPage: 0}).then(function(content) {
  console.log(content.facets_stats.myfacet.min, content.facets_stats.myfacet.max);
});
```

You could then save those values and setup your slider accordingly.